# Qt draw over vertical layout

Tags: c++, qt, paint, qpainter

I have `QVBoxLayout` with multiple children and I want to be able to draw on top of it. I've tried implementing `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` for the layout but everything I draw stays under the children. How can I do it? I'd be thankful for sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layouts don't have `paintEvent` member so you can't reimplement it. I'm surprised you managed to get some effect from this action.

1. Add new `QWidget` (let's call it wrapper) into your form and add your `QVBoxLayout` into this widget.
2. Create another widget (overlay) and add it to the wrapper using `setParent()`, not adding it into layout.
3. Reimplement overlay's paintEvent or add some other widgets to the overlay.

Simple example (tested):

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
public:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
    QWidget::paintEvent(e);
    QPainter p(this);
    p.fillRect(4, 4, 30, 30, QBrush(Qt::red));
  }
};

QWidget* wrapper = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(wrapper);
layout->addWidget(new QLabel("test1"));
layout->addWidget(new QLabel("test2"));
MyWidget* overlay = new MyWidget();
overlay->setParent(wrapper);
wrapper->show();
```